# Extend LayoutAnchorable to have use its own style

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I am using AvalonDock in my application to have a Visual Studio look and feel.  I would like to add some buttons and other controls to the header of the LayoutAnchorableControl as well as add some menu items to the drop down.  I only want this to affect certain controls and not the entire layout.

I've been able to add buttons and controls to specific LayoutAnchorableControls by adding methods to the LayoutAnchorable that check for certain criteria and adding the controls to the theme.  However, I feel there is a more robust solution I have yet to stumble on.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVVM approach, you don't need to add methods to `LayoutAnchorableControls`. You can get it simply editing AvalonDock style.

For example, you may edit the `LayoutDocumentTabItem` style like the following:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type avalonDockControls:LayoutDocumentTabItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <!--  Following border is required to catch mouse events  -->
                        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Background="Transparent" />

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Visibility="{Binding LayoutItem.Model.IsStatusQuadStringVisible,
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                       Text="{Binding LayoutItem.Model.StatusQuadString,
                                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" FontSize="{StaticResource SrkMainTouchControlFontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              Grid.Column="2"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Content="{Binding Model,
                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{Binding DocumentHeaderTemplate,
                                                                        Mode=OneWay,
                                                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type avalonDock:DockingManager},
                                                                                                       Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                              ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding DocumentHeaderTemplateSelector,
                                                                                Mode=OneWay,
                                                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type avalonDock:DockingManager},
                                                                                                               Mode=FindAncestor}}" />

                        <!--  region TabItem Buttons  -->
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center">

                            <Button Margin="2,0"
                                    Command="{Binding LayoutItem.Model.MyCustomCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonAvalonDocumentStyleKey}">
                                <Button.ToolTip>
                                    <PriorityBinding>
                                        <Binding Path="LayoutItem.Model.MyCustomCommand" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" IsAsync="True"/>
                                    </PriorityBinding>
                                </Button.ToolTip>
                                <Path Data="{StaticResource SrkGeometryMyCustomCommand}" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="5,0" Style="{StaticResource PathAvalonDocumentStyleWithStrokeKey}" />
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <!--  endregion TabItem Buttons  -->

                    </Grid>
                </Border>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

By doing this, you are adding a new custom `Button` to the tabbed Doc's title, binded to an `ICommand` named `MyCustomCommand`.
Furthermore, you may adding `DataTrigger` to the style binded to a `Visibility` property on the `ViewModel` that can handle button visibility, based on the business logic of your application.

I hope it helps.